# Mapping an Entity code first property to a different table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been asked to modify an existing application that passes EF entity object back from the business layer that are displayed in the front end. In a few spots there are records that have the OfficeCode logged in the database as a string. I have been asked on the frontend to now display the OfficeName for some of these records. Below is a snippet of these models.

```
public class Office
{
    [Key]
    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }

    public string OfficeName { get; set; }

    // Many more properties
}

public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string OfficeCode { get; set; } // Not a ForeignKey, I didn't create the database

    public string OfficeName { get; set; } // Can we pull this from the Office table?
}
```

I thought I might be able to use Entity Splitting but I get the error message

The entity types 'Office' and 'Note' cannot share table 'Office' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

Is there a way to populate a property from another table if there is no ForeignKey relationship between the tables?

Can someone think of an elegant way to display the OfficeName in the Notes without major repluming of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Interceptors concept of EF. IDbCommandInterceptor is allowing you to modfiy the SQL statement before executing and modify the results after executing.

You have to pass the parameter (OfficeCode) to your Interceptor and then modifying the sql query manually(.... from Office Where Note.OfficeCode = Office.OfficeCode )

http://xabikos.com/2014/11/18/Create-a-multitenant-application-with-Entity-Framework-Code-First-Part-2/

I do not know, why you are trying to make your live so difficult, You have noticed that EF does not like your data definition, Maybe you take a look to use Complex Types, or TPH and both entity share the same base column, this will be more easy.

Comment: I am not trying to make my life difficult, I am faced with an existing application. Normally I would select into DTO objects from an IQueriable, I would never hydrate Entity objects. I could just create a relationship between Note and Office and include Office but then I would have a complex Office object, 40+ properties, attached to each note all for the sake of one name property.